# Implement custom buttons/progressbar for VideoView player

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set my custom design for the VideoView controls like progress bar and play/pause buttons. For the last couple of hours I've been looking into MediaController class. It seems there's no easy way to customize it.

Should I abandon idea of using MediaController and switch to something else ? If yes - what would you suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many listners related to MediaPlayer that allow you to know the state of your song or video :)
So if you take a look to android documentation you'll find what you want.

[Documentation: MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Yeah, I've already thought of that - so do you think it's possible to make mediacontroller like on your own ?

Comment: Yes. Me and some classmates have done in two days at the hackathon a simple player as you can see in the picture at this link [Songr](http://alchemiasoft.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/ict-days-from-hackathon-with-love/).

Comment: Okay, I'll try it tonight. I'll leave the question open for a while though